# MyBatis Insert and Return Key - Annotations/Primatives/MySql

Tags: mybatis

I've got a bit of a corner case here. I'm wanting to insert into a MySql table with MyBatis configured via annotations and return the auto-increment key. My method is only using primitives though, not a POJO:

```
@Insert("INSERT into my_list (created_by_id, name) values (#{userId}, #{name})")
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true)
long insert(@Param("userId") long userId, @Param("name") String name);
```

How do I tell MyBatis to map the key back to the method return parameter (rather than a POJO member variable)?

I'm getting the exception:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is
org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: Error getting generated key or setting 
result to parameter object. 
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'id' not found. Available 
parameters are [userId, name, param1, param2]
```

Comment: Were you ever able to do this without going to a POJO solution?

Answer (score 0):

mybatis generate the id and set it to the id field in the pojo . but here you do not have the pojo for mybatis to set id.
if you don't have a pojo, you can use map, put all parameter into map and mybatis will put id to the map.

Comment: Yes - hence the question.